# Loop through subquery results to query same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that contains user event data. Some entries are revenue events and some entries are load events. The load events have url's that contain URL parameters and both revenue and load events have session_id and user_id data attached. I wrote a query that will pull the user and session IDs from this table based off of URL parameters on load events for the past 45 days and I would like to then look for revenue events with matching user and session IDs and total the amount for them. Here is my first query:

```sql
SELECT user_id, session_id 
FROM events
WHERE event_type = 'load'
  AND client_id = 1234
  AND calling_url LIKE '%utm_source=so%'
  AND server_stamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY) AND NOW()
```

A query that would get revenue from a single user would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(revenue_subtotal)
FROM events 
WHERE event_type = 'revenue'
  AND client_id = 1234
  AND user_id = 'thisUUID'
  AND session_id = 'thisSID'
```

So I am trying to find a way to link these two queries to sum up the revenue from all user/session ID combos returned from the first query directly in SQL (all in one full query).

Unfortunately this table has many columns so giving the full table definition and full sample data is a bit difficult to portray on SO but I think I have spelled it out well enough. Please let me know though if any more information is needed or any idea of how to accomplish this. As of right now the only way I have is to get the results of the first query in PHP then loop through a do a new query for each row returned, but this can easily get into the thousands so I'm trying to keep in all in SQL if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without sample data it's hard to be 100% certain but you should be able to do a self-join on the `client_id`, `user_id` and `session_id` to get the data you want:

```
SELECT e1.user_id, e1.session_id, COALESCE(SUM(e2.revenue_subtotal), 0) AS revenue
FROM events e1
LEFT JOIN events e2 ON e2.client_id = e1.client_id
                   AND e2.session_id = e1.session_id
                   AND e2.user_id = e1.user_id
                   AND e2.event_type = 'revenue'
WHERE e1.event_type = 'load'
  AND e1.client_id = 1234
  AND e1.calling_url LIKE '%utm_source=so%'
  AND e1.server_stamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY) AND NOW()    
GROUP BY e1.user_id, e1.session_id
```

Note we use a `LEFT JOIN` so we can still get a result when there are no `revenue` events, and `COALESCE` to make the output 0 in those cases.

Note also that you need a `GROUP BY` clause on this query to separate the results for each event.

Comment: I'm no longer in front of my computer so I can't test this out at the moment but will do so in the morning. If I have any issues, how would you recommend providing sample data? Its roughly 12-15 columns and some decently long strings in some rows (though I could probably shorten them some for sample data) so it wouldn't be very readable as text in a post.

Comment: @Xandor If you do have issues, probably just commenting with the difference between your actual & expected output should be enough to figure them out. Let me know. Note it's only late afternoon here so I might be a bit slow responding first thing.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Doesn't seem to be working right. I did have to remove an `AND` from the `WHERE` clause, there was one too many. Swapped the `?` out for a number (45) in this case. But the DB seems to become unresponsive after that. It seems almost to be creating an infinite loop or something of the sort. Let it sit for a good few minutes. But I can close it out and run a simple query and it is responding properly.

Comment: Okay, maybe it really is just taking that long. I removed the `JOIN` and just ran the base query and returned tens of thousands of rows and took over 1 second for that query alone. The cross referencing might be causing it to run a ridiculous amount of time though I let it sit for 10 minutes, I imagine it still shouldn't take that long. Attempting to create an index off of `user_id` and `session_is` but even that is taking some time. I might need to clear this DB out some while ironing this out. Any advice here?

Comment: Okay, this did it! I then used `SELECT` from the results of your query as a subquery to `SUM` unique users and revenue in total and it worked excellently. After creating an index on this data it took about 4 seconds for the full query. Note to future readers, an index on the `user_id` and `session_id` is needed for something like this to take a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Alright, I noticed a logical issue with what I am wanting to get returned and how I had first explained it but what I am actually wanting to achieve is to get a set of `load` events that match everything listed, no matter when that occurred. Then in the next section get revenue that matches the `user_id` and `session_id` within 45 days of the `load` event. I moved server stamp check to the on clause and re-wrote it like this: `AND e2.server_stamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(e1.server_stamp, INTERVAL 45 DAY) AND e1.server_stamp` but got unexpected results. Does this line look correct?

Comment: @Xandor I'm glad you've essentially got it working. It might also be of benefit to include `client_id` and `event_type` in the index as they are both used in the `JOIN` condition too (or possibly add a second index over those two columns). What you wrote for the date part of the `ON` condition looks ok - in what way are the results not what you expect?

Comment: I will definitely add that as an index as well. As far as results. It might be accurate. I just got a different revenue after moving the `BETWEEN` clause and I thought it would be the same because all the data was generated in the last 2 weeks. But I have simulated over 200K events in total and basically have too much data to confirm the accuracy but I believe it to be correct now. I will clear my database out and work with small sets to check it, but as far as the original issue it is resolved. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Xandor no worries. If you do find any issues feel free to ping me in a comment.